# Unit testing API responses

Tags: php, api, unit-testing, phpunit

I came across a scenario in which I am not sure how test.

My application communicates back and forth with the Zoho CRM API, using the official PHP SDK. Here is the portion of my user class that I am having trouble with:

```
class App_ZCRM_User {

    protected $record;


    public function __construct( ZCRMRecord $record ) {
        $this->record = $record;
    }


    public function create_default_tasks( array $tasks ) {
        $records = [];

        foreach( $tasks as $task ) {
            $record = ZCRMRecord::getInstance( 'Tasks', null ); // Create empty ZCRMRecord
            $record->setFieldValue( 'Subject', $task );
            $record->setFieldValue( 'User', $this->record );

            $records[] = $record;
        }

        $tasks  = ZCRMModule::getInstance( 'Tasks' );
        $insert = $tasks->createRecords( $records );

        // Returns array of EntityResponse objects
        return $insert->getEntityResponses();
    }
}
```

This class is instantiated with a Zoho CRM record using a contacts unique ID

```
// ZCRMRecord object
$record = ZCRMRecord::getInstance( 'Contacts', 'xxxxxxxxxx' );

$user = new App_ZCRM_User( $record );
$user->create_default_tasks( array(
     'Choose vehicle make',
     'Choose vehicle model',
) );
```

The `create_default_tasks()` method communicates with the Zoho API.

The concern I am running into is that I do not want these records inserted into the CRM everytime the test is run.

I tried mocking the ZCRMModule for Tasks, but the class has a private constructor and uses a static method `getInstance()`. Using `$tasks = ZCRMModule::getInstance( 'Tasks' );` and calling `$tasks->createRecords()` on this class will result in a live API request.

My test is below, but it returns the message:

> Static method "getInstance" cannot be invoked on mock object

```
public function test_create_default_tasks() {
        $tasks = array(
            'Task 1',
            'Task 2'
        );

        $records = [];

        foreach( $tasks as $task ) {
            $record = ZCRMRecord::getInstance( 'Tasks', null );
            $record->setFieldValue( 'Subject', $task );
            $record->setFieldValue( 'User', $this->record );

            $records[] = $record;
        }

        $user = new App_ZCRM_User( $this->record );
        $user->create_default_tasks( $tasks ); // Does API request


        /**
         * I want to mock the ZCRMModule tasks and simulate the createRecords() method
         */
        $tasks = $this->getMockBuilder( 'ZCRMModule' )
                      ->disableOriginalConstructor() // Constructor is private
                      ->getMock();

        $tasks::getInstance( 'Tasks' );
        $insert = $tasks->createRecords( $records ); // Method returns null

        $created = $insert->getEntityResponses();

        // Not sure how to assert the value here...
        //$this->assertEquals(  );
    }
```

I am lost trying to wrap my head arounds this... how can I test this method without using a live API request to Zoho ?

Comment: Why do you need to mock, if you only need to create a fake result set? `$insert = [..some data..];` won't work for you?

Comment: @FelippeDuarte wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the test in the first place? is this a method that even needs to be tested?

Comment: Usually we don't test API calls (except your own API). So, if your code does some API calls, make sure this piece of code is in a different class, let's say `class MakeAPICall`. Then you mock `MakeAPICall`. When your class call `MakeAPICall` object methods, you can set a expected return.

Comment: Creating a facade did cross my mind, thanks for your help